# Complex Xpath in junit-frames.xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, ant, junit

I am working on junit-frames.xsl file which is responsible for generating reports. I need to make some changes in the xsl file to adhere to our format for displaying the contents. i am finding difficulty to understand this complex Xpath. Can somebidy please help.

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="testsuite[not(./@package = preceding-sibling::testsuite/@package)]" mode="all.packages">
        <xsl:sort select="@package"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testsuite[not(./@package = preceding-sibling::testsuite/@package)]
```

xpath expression above means :

```
select element named `testsuite` that match following criteria :
have attribute `package` with value not equal to :
attribute `package` of any previous `testsuite` element
```

So if you have xml with following structure for example :

```
<parent>
    <testsuite package="value1" id="1"/>
    <testsuite package="value2" id="2"/>
    <testsuite package="value2" id="3"/>
    <testsuite package="value1" id="4"/>
</parent>
```

only the 1st and 2nd `<testsuite>` element will match above xpath expression.

Comment: so it will check with all previous siblings or just the previous sibling

Comment: all previous siblings

Comment: I've tested that to make sure. My updated answer shows the latest xml I used to test, and the result

Comment: Updated my answer with the correct one. I hope you didn't get confused by the answer before last update. With the sample I provide, the xpath query will return testsuite element with id 1 and 2.

Comment: To add to @har07's excellent answer, the XPath expression will also match every `testsuite` element that doesn't have a `package` attribute.